# Copying an array to cells

Tags: vba

I currently have an array full of data that I would like to transfer to cell G2 all the way until the entire array is exhausted. My current spreadsheet has data in G1 but no data under that.

I have the following code but it doesn't exactly work because I get the error:

Application-defined or object-defined error.

Help fixing this problem would be great. I would appreciate if you could tell me what is wrong with my code and how to fix it rather than providing me with an alternative formulation.

```
For i = 1 to nFlights
     With Worksheets("Q2").Range("G1")
           .End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = Origin(i)
    End With
Next
```

Comment: If there's no data below G1, then your first **.End(xlDown)** will take you to the last row on the sheet.  You're then trying to **Offset** that by another row, which can't be done.  You don't need the **.End()** ar all - just use **.Offset(i,0)**

Answer (score 8):

I know you didn't want to be shown code, but here's a different approach from your loop:

```
Dim arr
arr = Array("one","two","three","four")

ActiveSheet.Range("G2").Resize((UBound(arr) - LBound(arr)) + 1, 1).Value = _
                                  Application.Transpose(arr)
```

Comment: +1: interesting. Never used that Resize, but I'll definitely explore its uses.

Comment: +1 efficiently done. I liked the handling of the Option Base 0 or Option Base 1 by testing both upper and lower bounds.

Answer (score 0):

The offset property just references the cell (in your case), one below the cell that is the base of the call ("G1").  In order to copy the whole array orgin into the column G on the sheet try this:

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 2

For Each val As String In Origin
    With Worksheets("Q2")
       .Cells(i, 7).Value = Origin(i)
       i = i + 1
    End With
Next
```

Comment: I actually did have a loop. Can you look at my code above? I edited it with my for, next loop. What is wrong with it now? Also what does val represent? And how does the .Cells construction work? thanks.

Comment: Cells returns a range referencing the row/column provided.  In my example, it is the same as .Range("G2").  Your code will just stick each index of Origin into the same worksheet cell since you are not using i in the offset at all.